# Resize video source in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

i need to resize my webcam feed to a constant value like 430*315 to view from my j panel without resizing it only show a little area that is equal to the resized j panel um using OpenCV VideoCapture method for capture video from webcam

below is my code part that i used to do grab the frames

```
if (webSource.grab()) {
                    try {

                        webSource.retrieve(frame);

                        Graphics g = jPanel2.getGraphics();
```

i tried

```
 Size sz = new Size(430, 315);
 Imgproc.resize(frame, frame, sz);
```

and

```
webSource.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 430);
webSource.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 315);
```

i was unable to accomplish my requirement from any of that so is there a way that this can be done

Answer (score 0):

To get sections of a current image as a new image, use ROI (region of interest) to specify the section. The ROI is a rectangle here, which can be initialized several ways.

Sorry this is in C++, not Java;

Some ways to specify the region:

```
Rect ROI = Rect(Point(0, 0), Size(430, 315));
Rect ROI = Rect(0, 0, 430, 315);
Rect ROI = Rect(Point(x, y), Point(x + 430, y + 315));
```

Now to get a section of the captured frame:

```
Mat windowedframe = frame(ROI);
```

**WARNING:** This method doesn't care if the boundaries of the rectangle is located in the image or not, so if you go beyond the resolution of frame, it will crash.

Comment: This will **crop** the input image. What @Kavinda is asking is how to **resize** it.

Comment: @karlphillip I think resizing is something that had already beened tried, as the question includes working resize code.

Comment: thanku  benjamin as @karl said i need to resize it, and i use roi later to crop the  image in ditection part. i need to resize a video feed from itz original resolution to this given resolution

Answer (score 0):

While Capturing Frames from the Webcam you can resize using the resizing function.

```
// Using C++
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 430);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 315);
Mat image;
cap.read(image);
resize(image, image, Size(430, 315), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
namedWindow("firstframe", 1);
imshow("firstframe", image);
waitKey(0);
```

Maybe this can do the trick.

Comment: i try to use it bat cnnot get to work in java alwys gives a huge error list

Comment: you are targeting android for Opencv in java? for that you have to convert opencv libaries to equivalent java functions or you have to use native android.